# How do I update the position of different prefabs to the current position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

I'm making a game where the player is a square and it changes shape when he presses a key. To do that I made different prefabs because I have different things to change. When I press the key to change to one prefab, I set active the corresponding prefab and I disable the other. The problem is here, I have three prefabs and I don't know where to connect to change the position runtime. I tried to make the position equal to the others but it didn't work.

Here there is the code I made:

```
public class Transformation : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public GameObject normal, small, big;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("q"))
        {
            big.SetActive(true);
            normal.SetActive(false);
            small.SetActive(false);
            big.transform.position = normal.transform.position = small.transform.position;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("w"))
        {
            normal.SetActive(true);
            big.SetActive(false);
            small.SetActive(false);
            normal.transform.position = big.transform.position = small.transform.position;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
        {
            small.SetActive(true);
            normal.SetActive(false);
            big.SetActive(false);
            small.transform.position = big.transform.position = normal.transform.position;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Place all 3 prefabs in an empty scene and zero out their transforms.  Are they in the correct positions?  If not, this is because of the pivot point.  If the pivot point is the problem, you can either 1) fix the model  2) parent the model to an empty GO and center it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the location of these gameObjects to be moved to the location of the script object. It is better to try this:

```cs
void Update()
{
    small.SetActive(false);
    normal.SetActive(false);
    big.SetActive(false);
    
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("q"))
    {
        big.SetActive(true);
        big.transform.position = transform.position;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown("w"))
    {
        normal.SetActive(true);
        normal.transform.position = transform.position;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
    {
        small.SetActive(true);
        small.transform.position = transform.position;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make one empty `GameObject` and apply all movement logic to it. Put normal, small and big objects as children of the main `GameObject` and just enable/disable them as you need.